# What will be the output

Tags: python, string

## **Program**

This is my program

```
a=30
b=444.78
c="\nkuntal Ojha"
d='\nKunal Ojha\n'
e='''Srabanti & Kuntal'''
print(a,b,c,d,e)
```

## **Output**

In this output I  can't understand whay for printing e take a space before it's print.

```
30 444.78 
kuntal Ojha 
Kunal Ojha
 Srabanti & Kuntal
```

## Why not this **OUTPUT**

Tell Which out put is right first one or this one.
please tell me with the the example. I am a new #phthon learnar help me
to know more about python

```
30 444.78 
kuntal Ojha 
Kunal Ojha
Srabanti & Kuntal
```

Comment: because print() separates every argument with a space. in fact, there is a space right after each of a, b, c, d

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the default value of the `sep` is a space.

When it prints `d`, it ends with `\n`, moving the cursor to new line, after which `print` function adds a space (default separator) and prints value of `e`.

---

To eliminate it, we can change the default `sep` value.

## **Program**

```py
a=30
b=444.78
c="\nkuntal Ojha"
d='\nKunal Ojha\n'
e='''Srabanti & Kuntal'''
print(a,b,c,d,e, sep='')
```

## **Output**

```py
30444.78
kuntal Ojha
Kunal Ojha
Srabanti & Kuntal
```

---

If you pay attention, there is no space between value of `a` and `b` because we changed the `sep` to `''`(nothing).